# Rundeck upgrade from 3.3.5 to 3.4.10

Tags: upgrade, rundeck

Can someone share the procedure to upgrade rundeck 3.3.5 to 3.4.10

In order to over come  log4j security vulnerability

Answer (score 0):

The process is described [here](https://docs.rundeck.com/docs/upgrading/upgrading.html#general-upgrade-guide). Your instance is 3.3.5 so, you don't need to follow the [database migration process](https://docs.rundeck.com/docs/upgrading/upgrading-to-rundeck-3.4.html#db-migration), you can test in a non-prod env by launching the new instance over the old one.

Anyway, as good advice please backup all your instance data and test it in a non-prod environment before.

UPDATE 04/22/2022:

Rundeck 4.1.0 uses H2v2 as the default testing backend, please take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71972830/10426011) if you're using H2 as the default backend.