# Rundeck Runtime issue

Tags: java, upgrade, rundeck

I am trying to upgrade Rundeck war file from rundeck-3.4.3-20210823.war to rundeck-4.1.0-20220420.war and getting SQL statement errors can some please help us from this issue.

Upgrade steps followed by below URL:

https://docs.rundeck.com/docs/upgrading/upgrading.html#runnable-war

Error:

```
[2022-04-21T15:42:31,978] WARN  internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator - HHH000339: Could not obtain connection metadata: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLNonTransientException: General error: "The write format 1 is smaller than the supported format 2 [2.1.210/5]" [50000-210]
[2022-04-21T15:42:33,130] ERROR pool.ConnectionPool - Unable to create initial connections of pool.
org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLNonTransientException: General error: "The write format 1 is smaller than the supported format 2 [2.1.210/5]" [50000-210]
    at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:573) ~[h2-2.1.210.jar!/:?]
    at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:496) ~[h2-2.1.210.jar!/:?]
    at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:216) ~[h2-2.1.210.jar!/:?]
    at org.h2.mvstore.db.Store.convertMVStoreException(Store.java:166) ~[h2-2.1.210.jar!/:?]
    at org.h2.mvstore.db.Store.<init>(Store.java:140) ~[h2-2.1.210.jar!/:?]
    at org.h2.engine.Database.<init>(Database.java:324) ~[h2-2.1.210.jar!/:?]
    at org.h2.engine.Engine.openSession(Engine.java:92) ~[h2-2.1.210.jar!/:?]
    at org.h2.engine.Engine.openSession(Engine.java:222) ~[h2-2.1.210.jar!/:?]
    at org.h2.engine.Engine.createSession(Engine.java:201) ~[h2-2.1.210.jar!/:?]
    at org.h2.engine.SessionRemote.connectEmbeddedOrServer(SessionRemote.java:338) ~[h2-2.1.210.jar!/:?]
    at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcConnection.<init>(JdbcConnection.java:122) ~[h2-2.1.210.jar!/:?]
    at org.h2.Driver.connect(Driver.java:59) ~[h2-2.1.210.jar!/:?]
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.PooledConnection.connectUsingDriver(PooledConnection.java:319) ~[tomcat-jdbc-9.0.44.jar!/:?]
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.PooledConnection.connect(PooledConnection.java:212) ~[tomcat-jdbc-9.0.44.jar!/:?]
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.createConnection(ConnectionPool.java:744) ~[tomcat-jdbc-9.0.44.jar!/:?]
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.borrowConnection(ConnectionPool.java:676) ~[tomcat-jdbc-9.0.44.jar!/:?]
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.init(ConnectionPool.java:483) ~[tomcat-jdbc-9.0.44.jar!/:?]
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.<init>(ConnectionPool.java:154) ~[tomcat-jdbc-9.0.44.jar!/:?]
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceProxy.pCreatePool(DataSourceProxy.java:118) ~[tomcat-jdbc-9.0.44.jar!/:?]
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceProxy.createPool(DataSourceProxy.java:107) ~[tomcat-jdbc-9.0.44.jar!/:?]
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceProxy.getConnection(DataSourceProxy.java:131) ~[tomcat-jdbc-9.0.44.jar!/:?]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.LazyConnectionDataSourceProxy$LazyConnectionInvocationHandler.getTargetConnection(LazyConnectionDataSourceProxy.java:405) ~[spring-jdbc-5.3.18.jar!/:5.3.18]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.LazyConnectionDataSourceProxy$LazyConnectionInvocationHandler.invoke(LazyConnectionDataSourceProxy.java:378) ~[spring-jdbc-5.3.18.jar!/:5.3.18]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy161.getMetaData(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:?]
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[?:?]
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:?]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[?:?]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.TransactionAwareDataSourceProxy$TransactionAwareInvocationHandler.invoke(TransactionAwareDataSourceProxy.java:238) ~[spring-jdbc-5.3.18.jar!/:5.3.18]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy161.getMetaData(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:70) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.24.Final.jar!/:5.4.24.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:35) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.24.Final.jar!/:5.4.24.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.initiateService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:101) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.24.Final.jar!/:5.4.24.Final]
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.createService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:263) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.24.Final.jar!/:5.4.24.Final]
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:237) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.24.Final.jar!/:5.4.24.Final]
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:214) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.24.Final.jar!/:5.4.24.Final]
    at org.hibernate.id.factory.internal.DefaultIdentifierGeneratorFactory.injectServices(DefaultIdentifierGeneratorFactory.java:152) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.24.Final.jar!/:5.4.24.Final]
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.injectDependencies(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:286) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.24.Final.jar!/:5.4.24.Final]
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:243) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.24.Final.jar!/:5.4.24.Final]
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:214) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.24.Final.jar!/:5.4.24.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.<init>(InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.java:176) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.24.Final.jar!/:5.4.24.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.complete(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:118) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.24.Final.jar!/:5.4.24.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.build(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:83) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.24.Final.jar!/:5.4.24.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.MetadataBuilderImpl.build(MetadataBuilderImpl.java:473) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.24.Final.jar!/:5.4.24.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.MetadataBuilderImpl.build(MetadataBuilderImpl.java:84) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.24.Final.jar!/:5.4.24.Final]
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:689) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.24.Final.jar!/:5.4.24.Final]
    at org.grails.orm.hibernate.cfg.HibernateMappingContextConfiguration.buildSessionFactory(HibernateMappingContextConfiguration.java:287) ~[grails-datastore-gorm-hibernate5-7.2.2.jar!/:?]
    at org.grails.orm.hibernate.connections.HibernateConnectionSourceFactory.create(HibernateConnectionSourceFactory.java:86) ~[grails-datastore-gorm-hibernate5-7.2.2.jar!/:?]
    at org.grails.orm.hibernate.connections.AbstractHibernateConnectionSourceFactory.create(AbstractHibernateConnectionSourceFactory.java:39) ~[grails-datastore-gorm-hibernate5-7.2.2.jar!/:?]
    at org.grails.orm.hibernate.connections.AbstractHibernateConnectionSourceFactory.create(AbstractHibernateConnectionSourceFactory.java:23) ~[grails-datastore-gorm-hibernate5-7.2.2.jar!/:?]
    at org.grails.datastore.mapping.core.connections.AbstractConnectionSourceFactory.create(AbstractConnectionSourceFactory.java:64) ~[grails-datastore-core-7.2.1.jar!/:?]
    at org.grails.datastore.mapping.core.connections.AbstractConnectionSourceFactory.create(AbstractConnectionSourceFactory.java:52) ~[grails-datastore-core-7.2.1.jar!/:?]
    at org.grails.datastore.mapping.core.connections.ConnectionSourcesInitializer.create(ConnectionSourcesInitializer.groovy:24) ~[grails-datastore-core-7.2.1.jar!/:?]
    at org.grails.orm.hibernate.HibernateDatastore.<init>(HibernateDatastore.java:212) ~[grails-datastore-gorm-hibernate5-7.2.2.jar!/:?]
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) ~[?:?]
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[?:?]
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45) ~[?:?]
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:490) ~[?:?]
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:211) ~[spring-beans-5.3.18.jar!/:5.3.18]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:117) ~[spring-beans-5.3.18.jar!/:5.3.18]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:311) ~[spring-beans-5.3.18.jar!/:5.3.18]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:296) ~[spring-beans-5.3.18.jar!/:5.3.18]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1372) ~[spring-beans-5.3.18.jar!/:5.3.18]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1222) ~[spring-beans-5.3.18.jar!/:5.3.18]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:582) ~[spring-beans-5.3.18.jar!/:5.3.18]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542) ~[spring-beans-5.3.18.jar!/:5.3.18]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-5.3.18.jar!/:5.3.18]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.3.18.jar!/:5.3.18]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333) ~[spring-beans-5.3.18.jar!/:5.3.18]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208) ~[spring-beans-5.3.18.jar!/:5.3.18]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:276) ~[spring-beans-5.3.18.jar!/:5.3.18]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.addCandidateEntry(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1607) ~[spring-beans-5.3.18.jar!/:5.3.18]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1571) ~[spring-beans-5.3.18.jar!/:5.3.18]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveMultipleBeans(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1437) ~[spring-beans-5.3.18.jar!/:5.3.18]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1347) ~[spring-beans-5.3.18.jar!/:5.3.18]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1309) ~[spring-beans-5.3.18.jar!/:5.3.18]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredMethodElement.resolveMethodArguments(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:759) ~[spring-beans-5.3.18.jar!/:5.3.18]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredMethodElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:719) ~[spring-beans-5.3.18.jar!/:5.3.18]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:119) ~[spring-beans-5.3.18.jar!/:5.3.18]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessProperties(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:399) ~[spring-beans-5.3.18.jar!/:5.3.18]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1431) ~[spring-beans-5.3.18.jar!/:5.3.18]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:619) ~[spring-beans-5.3.18.jar!/:5.3.18]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542) ~[spring-beans-5.3.18.jar!/:5.3.18]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-5.3.18.jar!/:5.3.18]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.3.18.jar!/:5.3.18]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333) ~[spring-beans-5.3.18.jar!/:5.3.18]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208) ~[spring-beans-5.3.18.jar!/:5.3.18]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:330) ~[spring-beans-5.3.18.jar!/:5.3.18]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:113) ~[spring-beans-5.3.18.jar!/:5.3.18]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1707) ~[spring-beans-5.3.18.jar!/:5.3.18]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1452) ~[spring-beans-5.3.18.jar!/:5.3.18]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:619) ~[spring-beans-5.3.18.jar!/:5.3.18]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542) ~[spring-beans-5.3.18.jar!/:5.3.18]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-5.3.18.jar!/:5.3.18]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.3.18.jar!/:5.3.18]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333) ~[spring-beans-5.3.18.jar!/:5.3.18]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208) ~[spring-beans-5.3.18.jar!/:5.3.18]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:330) ~[spring-beans-5.3.18.jar!/:5.3.18]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:113) ~[spring-beans-5.3.18.jar!/:5.3.18]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveManagedList(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:428) ~[spring-beans-5.3.18.jar!/:5.3.18]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:173) ~[spring-beans-5.3.18.jar!/:5.3.18]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveConstructorArguments(ConstructorResolver.java:707) ~[spring-beans-5.3.18.jar!/:5.3.18]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:198) ~[spring-beans-5.3.18.jar!/:5.3.18]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1372) ~[spring-beans-5.3.18.jar!/:5.3.18]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1222) ~[spring-beans-5.3.18.jar!/:5.3.18]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:582) ~[spring-beans-5.3.18.jar!/:5.3.18]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542) ~[spring-beans-5.3.18.jar!/:5.3.18]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-5.3.18.jar!/:5.3.18]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.3.18.jar!/:5.3.18]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333) ~[spring-beans-5.3.18.jar!/:5.3.18]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208) ~[spring-beans-5.3.18.jar!/:5.3.18]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:330) ~[spring-beans-5.3.18.jar!/:5.3.18]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:113) ~[spring-beans-5.3.18.jar!/:5.3.18]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1707) ~[spring-beans-5.3.18.jar!/:5.3.18]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1452) ~[spring-beans-5.3.18.jar!/:5.3.18]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:619) ~[spring-beans-5.3.18.jar!/:5.3.18]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542) ~[spring-beans-5.3.18.jar!/:5.3.18]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-5.3.18.jar!/:5.3.18]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.3.18.jar!/:5.3.18]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333) ~[spring-beans-5.3.18.jar!/:5.3.18]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208) ~[spring-beans-5.3.18.jar!/:5.3.18]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:330) ~[spring-beans-5.3.18.jar!/:5.3.18]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:113) ~[spring-beans-5.3.18.jar!/:5.3.18]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1707) ~[spring-beans-5.3.18.jar!/:5.3.18]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1452) ~[spring-beans-5.3.18.jar!/:5.3.18]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:619) ~[spring-beans-5.3.18.jar!/:5.3.18]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542) ~[spring-beans-5.3.18.jar!/:5.3.18]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-5.3.18.jar!/:5.3.18]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.3.18.jar!/:5.3.18]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333) ~[spring-beans-5.3.18.jar!/:5.3.18]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:213) ~[spring-beans-5.3.18.jar!/:5.3.18]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.ServletContextInitializerBeans.getOrderedBeansOfType(ServletContextInitializerBeans.java:212) ~[spring-boot-2.6.2.jar!/:2.6.2]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.ServletContextInitializerBeans.getOrderedBeansOfType(ServletContextInitializerBeans.java:203) ~[spring-boot-2.6.2.jar!/:2.6.2]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.ServletContextInitializerBeans.addServletContextInitializerBeans(ServletContextInitializerBeans.java:97) ~[spring-boot-2.6.2.jar!/:2.6.2]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.ServletContextInitializerBeans.<init>(ServletContextInitializerBeans.java:86) ~[spring-boot-2.6.2.jar!/:2.6.2]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.getServletContextInitializerBeans(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:260) ~[spring-boot-2.6.2.jar!/:2.6.2]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.selfInitialize(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:234) ~[spring-boot-2.6.2.jar!/:2.6.2]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.jetty.ServletContextInitializerConfiguration.callInitializers(ServletContextInitializerConfiguration.java:65) [spring-boot-2.6.2.jar!/:2.6.2]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.jetty.ServletContextInitializerConfiguration.configure(ServletContextInitializerConfiguration.java:54) [spring-boot-2.6.2.jar!/:2.6.2]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.configure(WebAppContext.java:498) [jetty-webapp-9.4.44.v20210927.jar!/:9.4.44.v20210927]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1409) [jetty-webapp-9.4.44.v20210927.jar!/:9.4.44.v20210927]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:910) [jetty-server-9.4.44.v20210927.jar!/:9.4.44.v20210927]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.doStart(ServletContextHandler.java:288) [jetty-servlet-9.4.44.v20210927.jar!/:9.4.44.v20210927]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:524) [jetty-webapp-9.4.44.v20210927.jar!/:9.4.44.v20210927]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:73) [jetty-util-9.4.44.v20210927.jar!/:9.4.44.v20210927]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:169) [jetty-util-9.4.44.v20210927.jar!/:9.4.44.v20210927]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.start(Server.java:423) [jetty-server-9.4.44.v20210927.jar!/:9.4.44.v20210927]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:110) [jetty-util-9.4.44.v20210927.jar!/:9.4.44.v20210927]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:97) [jetty-server-9.4.44.v20210927.jar!/:9.4.44.v20210927]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:387) [jetty-server-9.4.44.v20210927.jar!/:9.4.44.v20210927]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:73) [jetty-util-9.4.44.v20210927.jar!/:9.4.44.v20210927]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.jetty.JettyWebServer.initialize(JettyWebServer.java:123) [spring-boot-2.6.2.jar!/:2.6.2]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.jetty.JettyWebServer.<init>(JettyWebServer.java:90) [spring-boot-2.6.2.jar!/:2.6.2]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.jetty.JettyServletWebServerFactory.getJettyWebServer(JettyServletWebServerFactory.java:447) [spring-boot-2.6.2.jar!/:2.6.2]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.jetty.JettyServletWebServerFactory.getWebServer(JettyServletWebServerFactory.java:181) [spring-boot-2.6.2.jar!/:2.6.2]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.createWebServer(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:182) [spring-boot-2.6.2.jar!/:2.6.2]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.onRefresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:160) [spring-boot-2.6.2.jar!/:2.6.2]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:577) [spring-context-5.3.18.jar!/:5.3.18]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:145) [spring-boot-2.6.2.jar!/:2.6.2]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:730) [spring-boot-2.6.2.jar!/:2.6.2]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:412) [spring-boot-2.6.2.jar!/:2.6.2]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:302) [spring-boot-2.6.2.jar!/:2.6.2]
    at grails.boot.GrailsApp.run(GrailsApp.groovy:99) [grails-core-5.1.6.jar!/:5.1.6]
    at grails.boot.GrailsApp.run(GrailsApp.groovy:485) [grails-core-5.1.6.jar!/:5.1.6]
    at grails.boot.GrailsApp.run(GrailsApp.groovy:472) [grails-core-5.1.6.jar!/:5.1.6]
    at grails.boot.GrailsApp$run.call(Unknown Source) [grails-core-5.1.6.jar!/:?]
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:47) [groovy-3.0.9.jar!/:3.0.9]
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:125) [groovy-3.0.9.jar!/:3.0.9]
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:148) [groovy-3.0.9.jar!/:3.0.9]
    at rundeckapp.Application.main(Application.groovy:32) [classes!/:?]
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:?]
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[?:?]
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:?]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[?:?]
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:49) [rundeck-4.1.0-20220420.war:?]
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:108) [rundeck-4.1.0-20220420.war:?]
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:58) [rundeck-4.1.0-20220420.war:?]
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.WarLauncher.main(WarLauncher.java:59) [rundeck-4.1.0-20220420.war:?]
Caused by: org.h2.mvstore.MVStoreException: The write format 1 is smaller than the supported format 2 [2.1.210/5]
    at org.h2.mvstore.DataUtils.newMVStoreException(DataUtils.java:1004) ~[h2-2.1.210.jar!/:?]
    at org.h2.mvstore.MVStore.getUnsupportedWriteFormatException(MVStore.java:1059) ~[h2-2.1.210.jar!/:?]
    at org.h2.mvstore.MVStore.readStoreHeader(MVStore.java:878) ~[h2-2.1.210.jar!/:?]
    at org.h2.mvstore.MVStore.<init>(MVStore.java:455) ~[h2-2.1.210.jar!/:?]
    at org.h2.mvstore.MVStore$Builder.open(MVStore.java:4056) ~[h2-2.1.210.jar!/:?]
    at org.h2.mvstore.db.Store.<init>(Store.java:129) ~[h2-2.1.210.jar!/:?]
    ... 173 more
[2022-04-21T15:42:33,134] WARN  internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator - HHH000339: Could not obtain connection metadata: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLNonTransientException: General error: "The write format 1 is smaller than the supported format 2 [2.1.210/5]" [50000-210]
[2022-04-21T15:42:33,135] WARN  webapp.WebAppContext - Failed startup of context o.s.b.w.e.j.JettyEmbeddedWebAppContext@3467d540{application,/,[org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.jetty.JettyServletWebServerFactory$LoaderHidingResource@67710b92, jar:file:/ngs/app/dcf5d/rundeck/rundeck-4.1.0-20220420.war!/WEB-INF/lib/jquery-3.5.1.jar!/META-INF/resources],UNAVAILABLE}
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'rundeckPreauthFilterDeReg': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'rundeckPreauthFilter' while setting bean property 'filter'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'rundeckPreauthFilter': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'authenticationManager' while setting bean property 'authenticationManager'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'authenticationManager': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'daoAuthenticationProvider' while setting constructor argument with key [0]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'daoAuthenticationProvider': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'userDetailsService' while setting bean property 'userDetailsService'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'userDetailsService': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'setTargetDatastore' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'hibernateDatastore': Bean instantiation via constructor failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.grails.orm.hibernate.HibernateDatastore]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is org.hibernate.service.spi.ServiceException: Unable to create requested service [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.spi.JdbcEnvironment]
```

Comment: Hi! Could you elaborate? Are you using some database as a backend?

Comment: I would think the 1st thing is to contact rundeck tech support, no?

Comment: Hi OldProgrammer, the dedicated tech support is for Process Automation On Prem (Formely Rundeck Enterprise).

Comment: Hi MehaDrive68k, I have followed below link for database migration steps..

https://docs.rundeck.com/docs/upgrading/upgrading-to-rundeck-3.4.html#package-repositories

Still i am facing the same issue. Please suggest if anything i am missing here.

Comment: Hi Rajesh, Which database and version are you using? Could you share (at the question) the full stack trace?

Comment: Rajesh, the database migration process isn't needed for Rundeck 3.3.5 or above. Could you try again in a non-prod environment? (without the DB migration process)

Comment: Yeah, I am trying in non-prod only.. Initially i have tried without DB migration but its issue occurs then i have seen few blogs and i have followed.

Comment: Existing data base is h2.  Updating Full stack trace in the description,

Answer (score 1):

**Problem context**

Rundeck versions before 4.1.0 use the H2v1 database as the default testing backend, 4.1.0 and above use H2v2, H2v2 fixes a lot of issues but the bad news here is that doesn't exist a way to upgrade this H2v1 to h2v2 automatically (because H2v2 breaks the compatibility with H2v1 drivers).

You can read more about this [here](https://docs.rundeck.com/docs/upgrading/upgrading-to-4.1.html#h2-database-upgrade).

**So, you have two alternatives**

1. Start your previous instance, [backup](https://docs.rundeck.com/docs/administration/maintenance/backup.html#backup-and-recovery) all projects and keys, run 4.1.0 against a real database backend like MySQL or PostgreSQL and then [import](https://docs.rundeck.com/docs/administration/maintenance/backup.html#project-import-and-export) your projects and keys. [Here](https://docs.rundeck.com/docs/administration/configuration/database/#database-overview) you can see how to configure against a "real" backend.
2. Migrate your old H2v1 (Rundeck 3.4.3) database to H2v2 (Rundeck 4.1.0) using [this](https://github.com/rundeck-plugins/h2-v2-migration) script following [these](https://github.com/rundeck-plugins/h2-v2-migration#preparation) steps.

Definitely, the recommended option is the **first one**, H2 is a database **only** for testing purposes, not for production environments.

You can read more about it [here](https://docs.rundeck.com/docs/administration/configuration/database/#default-database).

*"Don't use the H2 embedded database for anything except testing and non-production."*

**UPDATE 04/25/2022:**

Some steps to move to a "real database" latest Rundeck instance:

1. Upgrade all your server data.
2. Start your old instance and follow [this](https://docs.rundeck.com/docs/administration/maintenance/backup.html#export-an-archive) to backup your projects and [this](https://docs.rundeck.com/docs/administration/maintenance/backup.html#export-import-keys) to backup your keys. Also, make sure to backup your model sources (`resources.xml` or `resources.yaml` files).
3. Stop the old instance.
4. Upgrade your instance following [this](https://docs.rundeck.com/docs/upgrading/) and remove the `{RUNDECK_HOME}/server/config/bootstrap.yml` file (or `/etc/rundeck/bootstrap.yml` file).
5. Create a new database following [this](https://docs.rundeck.com/docs/administration/configuration/database/#database-overview), make sure to configure Rundeck correctly. Check the MySQL [example](https://docs.rundeck.com/docs/administration/configuration/database/mysql.html#configuring-rundeck).
6. Start the 4.1.0 instance and import your projects following [this](https://docs.rundeck.com/docs/administration/maintenance/backup.html#import-an-archive) (using the files exported in the second step).

Comment: Hi Team, I have followed the first option but still having issue while starting the rundeck application.

Comment: Hi Rajesh, could you elaborate? which steps are you following? the error appears when starting the old instance or when running the new one against MySQL/PostgreSQL?

Comment: I added a few steps to upgrade to the new Rundeck version against a "real database".

Comment: I have followed the below link https://docs.rundeck.com/docs/upgrading/upgrading-to-4.1.html#h2-database-upgrade.   -- The error appears while staring the old instance only..

Comment: Rajesh, if you decided to follow the 2nd way (the h2 upgrade process), please follow this guide: https://github.com/rundeck-plugins/h2-v2-migration#preparation. Now, I'm not sure what is your current process when you say "I have followed the first option", the first option is to move your projects to MySQL/PostgreSQL/Oracle.

Comment: Sorry, I have followed the second option only..

Comment: Thank You MegaDrive68k, Finally, I can upgrade rundeck war file to latest one. While starting the server getting some WARN jdbc messages. Can you please check..