# Rundeck service not running after upgrade 3.4.0 to 4.8.0

Tags: rundeck

I am using rundeck community edition version 3.4.0. I have to upgrade 4.8.0 version. So I have used .deb  file to upgrade. After upgrade 4.8.0 rundeck service not running.

```
● rundeckd.service - LSB: rundeck job automation console
     Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/rundeckd; generated)
     Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Sat 2023-02-18 13:35:29 IST; 19min ago
       Docs: man:systemd-sysv-generator(8)
    Process: 64462 ExecStart=/etc/init.d/rundeckd start (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
   Main PID: 64472 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Feb 18 13:35:04 dockermachine systemd[1]: Starting LSB: rundeck job automation console...
Feb 18 13:35:04 dockermachine rundeckd[64462]:  * Starting rundeckd
Feb 18 13:35:04 dockermachine rundeckd[64462]:    ...done.
Feb 18 13:35:04 dockermachine systemd[1]: Started LSB: rundeck job automation console.
Feb 18 13:35:29 dockermachine systemd[1]: rundeckd.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Feb 18 13:35:29 dockermachine systemd[1]: rundeckd.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

**Service.log**

```
[2023-02-18T13:35:11,169] INFO  rundeckapp.Application - The following 1 profile is active: "production"

Configuring Spring Security Core ...
... finished configuring Spring Security Core

[2023-02-18T13:35:26,201] ERROR pool.ConnectionPool - Unable to create initial connections of pool.
org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLNonTransientException: General error: "The write format 1 is smaller than the supported format 2 [2.1.210/5]" [50000-210]
        at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:573) ~[h2-2.1.210.jar!/:?]
        at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:496) ~[h2-2.1.210.jar!/:?]
        at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:216) ~[h2-2.1.210.jar!/:?]
        at org.h2.mvstore.db.Store.convertMVStoreException(Store.java:166) ~[h2-2.1.210.jar!/:?]
        at org.h2.mvstore.db.Store.<init>(Store.java:140) ~[h2-2.1.210.jar!/:?]
        at org.h2.engine.Database.<init>(Database.java:324) ~[h2-2.1.210.jar!/:?]
        at org.h2.engine.Engine.openSession(Engine.java:92) ~[h2-2.1.210.jar!/:?]
        at org.h2.engine.Engine.openSession(Engine.java:222) ~[h2-2.1.210.jar!/:?]
        at org.h2.engine.Engine.createSession(Engine.java:201) ~[h2-2.1.210.jar!/:?]
        at org.h2.engine.SessionRemote.connectEmbeddedOrServer(SessionRemote.java:338) ~[h2-2.1.210.jar!/:?]
        at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcConnection.<init>(JdbcConnection.java:122) ~[h2-2.1.210.jar!/:?]
        at org.h2.Driver.connect(Driver.java:59) ~[h2-2.1.210.jar!/:?]
        at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.PooledConnection.connectUsingDriver(PooledConnection.java:319) ~[tomcat-jdbc-9.0.44.jar!/:?]
        at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.PooledConnection.connect(PooledConnection.java:212) ~[tomcat-jdbc-9.0.44.jar!/:?]
        at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.createConnection(ConnectionPool.java:744) ~[tomcat-jdbc-9.0.44.jar!/:?]
        at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.borrowConnection(ConnectionPool.java:676) ~[tomcat-jdbc-9.0.44.jar!/:?]
        at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.init(ConnectionPool.java:483) ~[tomcat-jdbc-9.0.44.jar!/:?]
        at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.<init>(ConnectionPool.java:154) ~[tomcat-jdbc-9.0.44.jar!/:?]
        at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceProxy.pCreatePool(DataSourceProxy.java:118) ~[tomcat-jdbc-9.0.44.jar!/:?]
        at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceProxy.createPool(DataSourceProxy.java:107) ~[tomcat-jdbc-9.0.44.jar!/:?]
        at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceProxy.getConnection(DataSourceProxy.java:131) ~[tomcat-jdbc-9.0.44.jar!/:?]
        at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.LazyConnectionDataSourceProxy.afterPropertiesSet(LazyConnectionDataSourceProxy.java:164) ~[spring-jdbc-5.3.20.jar!/:5.3.20]
        at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.LazyConnectionDataSourceProxy.<init>(LazyConnectionDataSourceProxy.java:108) ~[spring-jdbc-5.3.20.jar!/:5.3.20]
        at org.grails.datastore.gorm.jdbc.connections.DataSourceConnectionSourceFactory.proxy(DataSourceConnectionSourceFactory.java:100) ~[grails-datastore-gorm-7.2.1.jar!/:?]
        at org.grails.datastore.gorm.jdbc.connections.DataSourceConnectionSourceFactory.create(DataSourceConnectionSourceFactory.java:93) ~[grails-datastore-gorm-7.2.1.jar!/:?]
        at org.grails.datastore.gorm.jdbc.connections.CachedDataSourceConnectionSourceFactory.create(CachedDataSourceConnectionSourceFactory.java:37) ~[grails-datastore-gorm-7.2.1.jar!/:?]
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

That is a know issue described [here](https://docs.rundeck.com/docs/upgrading/upgrading-to-4.1.html#h2-database-upgrade).

Basically, since Rundeck 4.1 the default H2 backend was migrated to H2V2 (previous versions use H2V1). In [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71972830/10426011) StackOverflow answer you can see the two alternatives that you have to solve it, the main recommendation is to follow the first one: Configure your Rundeck instance against a "real" backend like MySQL or PostgreSQL, take a look at [this](https://docs.rundeck.com/docs/administration/configuration/database/#database-overview).

H2 backend [isn't designed for production instances](https://docs.rundeck.com/docs/administration/configuration/database/#default-database-h2), it's only for dev or testing environments.